# How to forward JavaScript console to Cocoa XWebView?

Tags: javascript, webview, ios8, xwebview

I wonder if it is anyhow possible to display the output of the JavaScript console to the console in the XCode editor. We use XWebView on iOS 8.

Googling seems not to help. I don't really have any idea.

Comment: Thanks for the new xwebview tag :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new [pull request](https://github.com/XWebView/XWebView/pull/28)(will be merged soon hopefully) for logging. You can create a object of the new `XWVLogging` class and load it into your webview object. For example:

```
let logger = XWVLogging(facility: "webapp")
webview.loadPlugin(logger, namespace: "console.syslog")
```

After binding the logger to namespace `console.syslog`, you can call the `console.syslog` function to send log to Xcode console, and also syslog server of iOS if level is higher than Info(6).

```
var level = 6;  // Info level, see man page of syslog(1)
console.syslog("Hello from Javascript", level);
```

Or use the simple notation of level:

```
console.syslog("+Hello from Javascript");
```

The leading "+" symbol means Info level. Check the code for other symbols of levels.

However, it doesn't redirect messages from javascript console to Xcode console. You need a wrapper to replace `console.log` function for doing that. It should be simple.

Any problems or suggestions, please open issues on GitHub.